# Centering & Vertically Align Image for image carousel inside <li>

Tags: html, css

I created my own image carousel, where I have an image and a caption as sibling elements. I had been setting my image to `position: relative;` and using `vertical-align: middle;` but that kept messing up the caption positioning, which is set to `position: absolute;`.

If you look at ***[My Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1wwa4jxm/2/)*** you can see how the image is no where near the center of the the `<li>` and just can't seem to get this to work. Have tried various combinations of relative positioning but still the caption always seems to give me an issue once the image is in the right spot.

Looking for a universal solution, that will work no matter what size the image.

### Here is my HTML

```
<div class="carousel">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <img src="someImage.jpg">
            <span class="caption">Some Caption</span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="someImage.jpg">
            <span class="caption">Some Caption</span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

### My CSS

```
.carousel img {
    max-height: 200px;
    max-width: 200px;
    /*vertical-align: middle;*/
    position: absolute;
}
.carousel li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.1s cubic-bezier(.91, .8, 0, 1);
    -moz-transition: all 0.1s cubic-bezier(.91, .8, 0, 1);
    -ms-transition: all 0.1s cubic-bezier(.91, .8, 0, 1);
    -o-transition: all 0.1s cubic-bezier(.91, .8, 0, 1);
    transition: all 0.1s cubic-bezier(.91, .8, 0, 1);
}
.carousel .caption {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: rgba(240,240,240,0.75);
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 5px 0 5px 0;
    width: 200px;
    max-width: 200px;
}
```

Any and all help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure there are far better and more elegant solutions than this one, however this is what I personally use when it comes to center multiple images in a row to some vertical center.

My idea is to wrap your image tags inside 2 div, something like this:

```
|----------------------------|
|.outer-image-wrap           |
|   |------------------------|
|   |.inner-image-wrap       |
|   |    --------------------|
|   |    |      <img/>       |
|___|____|___________________|
```

First off, `remove position: absolute from img`

For the `.outer-image-wrap`, set it to `display: table`, `height: 100%`, `width: 100%`;

Then for the `.inner-image-wrap`, set it to `display: table-cell`; and `vertical-align: middle`

Its not the most elegant solution out there, and I'm sure there are probably some better, but
it gets the job done without too much trouble. You can check it out [**here**:](http://jsfiddle.net/1wwa4jxm/8/)

Answer (score 0):

Solve by adding this:

```
.carousel img {
    margin-left: -100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

very simple 
http://jsfiddle.net/1wwa4jxm/3/

I hope you find what you need here and change it to your liking.

```
img {
width:100px;
display:block;
}
li {
display:inline-block;
text-align:center;
padding:20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a css rule for the span containing the caption:

```
.carousel span {
  max-height: 200px;
  max-width: 200px;
  margin-left: 80px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/1wwa4jxm/5/